# use of std::bsearch issues no suitable conversion function error for comparator

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this use of `std::bsearch` that accesses `some_file` defined in scope of this function:

```
int foo = bsearch(&key, (int *)arr + 1, count, sizeof(int), 
                 [&](int *offset_a, int *offset_b) -> int
                    { string name_a = *(string *)((int *)some_file + *offset_a);
                    });
```

and I get:

> no suitable conversion function from "lambda [](const int *offset_a,
> const int *offset_b)->int" to "__compar_fn_t" existsC/C++(413)

I was wondering how I can fix this without compromising functionality.

Comment: You cannot convert a lambda with caprture to a C style function pointer (as expected by `bsearch`).

Comment: Why are you using the C function bsearch instead of a strongly typed C++ equivalent such as [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)? I'd show an example but your code contains other errors, and without further information it isn't obvious what you wanted to actually achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [`std::bsearch` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/bsearch):

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the
> following:
>
> ```
> int cmp(const void *a, const void *b);
> ```

I.e. `comp` should be a C style function pointer or something that can be converted to one.

A lambda with capture (like in your case due to the `[&]`) cannot be converted into a C style function pointer.
This is because lambdas with capture are actually under-the-hood classes with a call operator, and data members for the captures.
Some more info: [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

You'll need to either use a plain function pointer, or a lambda without any capture.

---

Edit:
Alternatively (as @KonradRudolph commented), you can replace the C function `bsearch` with a similar C++ function, e.g. [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), where you can pass any lambda for the   comparator.